# Count the number of occurrences of each variant of an enum

Tags: rust, count, hashmap

I am trying to write a function to calculate poker hands. For this I need to check how many duplicates of each card value exist. I know this can be done with hashmaps, but I was wondering if it can also be done with some sort of statically allocated memory e.g. arrays given that the number of variants in the enum is known at compile time.

```
#[derive(Debug, Clone, PartialEq, Eq)]
enum Value {
    Ace,
    King,
    Queen,
    Jack,
    Ten,
    Nine,
    Eight,
    Seven,
    Six,
    Five,
    Four,
    Three,
    Two,
}
```

P.S. I'm pretty sure rust has a function for taking a vector or slice and returning a `HashMap` containing the counts of each distinct element in it e.g.

```
let a = vec![1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 4]
let b = a.counts();
let mut c = HashMap<i32, usize> = HashMap::new();
c.insert(1, 2);
c.insert(2, 2);
c.insert(3, 1);
c.insert(4, 1);
assert_eq(b, c);
```

However, I haven't been able to find it. Does anyone know what this function is?

Comment: [The function you are looking for](https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.counts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By casting enum variants to integers, this can efficiently be solved by using an array with the counts instead of a hash-map: ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=75691c690925013a5f2011e70c5718db))

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy, PartialEq, Eq)]
enum Value {
    Ace,
    King,
    Queen,
    Jack,
    Ten,
    Nine,
    Eight,
    Seven,
    Six,
    Five,
    Four,
    Three,
    Two,
}

fn counter<I>(iter: I) -> [u64;13]
where
    I: Iterator<Item = Value>
{
    let mut count = [0u64;13];
    for v in iter {
        let i = v as usize;
        count[i] += 1;
    }
    count
}

fn main() {
    let a = [Value::Ace, Value::Two, Value::Two];
    let b = counter(a.iter().copied());
    dbg!(b);
}
```

Comment: I feel like `counter` should return a `[usize; 13]` on account of counts generally being `usize` in Rust.

Comment: @BallpointBen Only things that are memory indices should be `usize`. Counting can and should use `u32` or `u64`, depending on whether the count is expected to be very large.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman What about `Vec::len`, `Iterator::count`, and `<const N: usize>` generics?

Comment: @BallpointBen `Vec::len()` returns the length of in memory data. Memory operations usually work with `usize`. `Iterator::count()` is a borderline, but because it is a generic function where you cannot predict the data size, `usize` is somewhat appropriate. `const N: usize` usually serves as array length.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in function for this, but it's trivial to write using [`Iterator::fold`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.fold):

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::hash::Hash;

fn counts<T: Eq + Hash>(items: impl IntoIterator<Item = T>) -> HashMap<T, usize> {
    items.into_iter().fold(HashMap::new(), |mut counts, i| {
        *counts.entry(i).or_default() += 1;
        counts
    })
}
```

Comment: It's available as [`Itertools::unique()`](https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.unique).

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I think you mean `counts`, but yes. That's not part of the standard library.

Comment: @cdhowie thanks, that was what I was thinking of. TBH I use itertools so much I forget it isn't part of the standard library